# Sort int queqe with restrictions

Tags: java, sorting, queue

I need to sort a queue using only one other queue, final number of variables and only with "isEmpty","enqueue","dequeue".
I'v tried to do this for a day and I just didn't figured it out yet..I searched all over the place and there is no question with that kind of restrictions, do you think that  it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822952/how-would-i-sort-a-queue-using-only-one-additional-queue

Comment: @dm1530 - that `duplicate` does not include bottom up merge sort as a potential answer.

Answer (score 0):

if it's in java , this is a normal bubble sort.

```
public void sort(Queue<Integer> q){

    //save first num into copy
    Queue<Integer> copy = new Queue<Integer>();
    int length=0;
    while(!q.isEmpty()){

        copy.add(q.remove());
        length ++;
    }

    int maxNum, temp;
    while(!copy.isEmpty()){

        maxNum=copy.remove();
        temp=0;        
        copy.add(maxNum);
        //search for the max number
        for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++){
            temp = copy.remove();
            if(temp > maxNum) maxNum= temp;
            copy.add(temp);
        }
        //delete it from copy and add it to q
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){

            temp = copy.remove();    
            if(temp == max){
                 q.add(max);
                 break;
            }
            copy.add(temp);
        }
        length --;
    }
}
```

it should work.
so , explanation:

count q and save it in copy.
now you can irritate through copy knowing how many values there are in it.
so search for the max number , insert it into q and remove from it copy.
after you've done that , decrement length , because
now copy has one less element and repeat until length==0 
and q is sorted.

the algorithm that sorts q and takes two more queues goes like this:
foreach element in q
while inserting q into a copy , find it's max number.
make sure you somehow inserted q into copy without the max number 
and then insert it into a new sorted queue.
after you've done that , reinsert copy into q and repeat until q is empty
at the end.

the whole point in that algorithm is that we use
one extra queue to irritate through q. 
and another in order to save the result while irritating.
because if we won't use another queue to irritate through q
we won't be able to know when to stop irritating.

but if we know when to stop irritating through q (knowing it's length)
we don't really need that extra queue, so we can use only one other queue.

I don't think you even need another queue. give me 
half of an hour and I will program you an algorithm using
only the queue we got.

when you sort an array , using the
types of sorting algorithms that we have currently have,
in order to sort it in less than O(n^2), you have to use memory of O(n);
which is the same as saying you will NEVER use a final number of variables
if you want less than O(n^2).
you wanted it to use a final number of variables , so I automatically assumed that you just needed a simple O(n^2) algorithm.
I think you can do merge sort. I'll do it tommorow.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much!
Second, I'm sure that there is a way, like you say, when you don't even need the other queue, but my purpuse was (and sorry for saying that now) that the algorithm will be inefficient, do you think that there is a way to do it in less than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

What is *final number of variables* ? Missing from the problem statement is how the front elements of each queue can be compared. Is there a size function that returns the number of elements in a queue?

For 2 queues, a bottom up merge sort can be implemented, but requires a few variables for each queue to keep track of a logical boundary in each queue. The logical boundary effectively splits each queue into two parts, a front (old) part and a back (new) part. This is a sort with time complexity of O(n log(n)).

Call the two queues A and B, with all the elements on A. If there is no size function, copy A to B to generate a count of elements.

Separate the elements evenly between A and B (one to A, one to B, ... ).

The merge sort repeatedly merges a run from A and B, alternating the merged run output between A and B. On the first pass, runs of size 1 are merged to form runs of size 2, the next pass runs of size 2 are merged to form runs of size 4, and so on, until the final pass where 2 runs are merged onto a single queue.